# How do I hotlink email addresses in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset that returns with individuals email addresses.  I would like the ability to just click on them and boom up pops a message addressed to that person just like in any other MS application.

I tried right-clicking the field, go to properties, then the action tab, and point the "go to url" to the email column list in the data set and no go.

This seems like a no brainer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has to be a valid URL link, not just an email address, so you have to prepend it with "mailto:". For example, make the navigation URL be an expression like:

```
="mailto:" & Fields!EmailAddress.Value
```

For bonus points, add a subject:

```
="mailto:" & Fields!EmailAddress.Value & "?subject=This report is great!"
```

Or even a subject and a body:

```
="mailto:" & Fields!EmailAddress.Value & "?subject=This report is great!&body=You deserve a raise!"
```

Of course, the expression for the Value property of the cell should remain just as the email address.

Comment: Three years later, this still still valid! Thanks!

Comment: That's a "must see" for SSRS makers

Comment: This is freaking awesome! I'm curious though, can I also add a body message to it as well with something like "?body=This is the main message" ?

Comment: @AlexWatts Yes, added body to answer

Comment: Also note that it might need to be explicitly formatted as mailto:// not just mailto: -- for example, in SSRS 2008 Text Action URL

Answer (score 1):

```
="MailTo:" + Fields!EMAIL.Value & "?Subject=" + Fields!SUBJECT.Value
```